# change view without realoding the page

Tags: angular, view

I have a contact form. on clicking the submit button, the contents filled in the contactform must be displayed on a different view without reloading the page.
I am thinking of having 2 different components and a boolean variable

initially set the boolean to true and display the component containing the contact form, when the submit button is clicked , set the boolean to false and display the content of the other component

I am new to angular and I am not able to get started with the code. 
How do I connect these two components , so that the data user entered in one component is sent to other component and displayed, also how both components can keep track of the boolean nvalue.

Comment: would be great, if you can show what you have done so far. checkout for master detail layout, start with input output properties  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: A simple solution without adding a state management library like Ngrx, would be to simply store the `.value` of the form as stringified JSON in session storage. On your next component, hydrate the string back to JSON.